# How to label individual molecules in a chemfig reaction scheme?

Tags: chemfig

I've looked all around, and can't even find this information in the chemfig manual. I'm attempting to label individual molecules in my chemfig reaction scheme. How to do this?

I've tried inluding the individual molecules as figures (`\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`) within the reaction scheme, but I ended up with a bunch of compilation errors. If using figures is actually the solution, how should that be achieved? Again, my final goal is labelling the individual molecules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\chemname{\chemfig{...}}{<molecule name>}` at page 23 of the chemfig manual.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \schemestart
    \chemname{\chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOR)---)}}{Molecule A}
    \arrow{->[\parbox{2cm}{\centering conjugation \\hydroxylation \\ oxidation}][]}[0,2]
    \chemname{\chemfig{**6(--(-COOR)-(-COOH)---)}}{Molecule B}
    \arrow{->}
    \chemname{\chemfig{**6(--(-[:-30](=[:-90]O)-[:30]O-[:-30]R)-(-[:30](=[:90]O)-[:-30]O-[:30](*6(-(-OH)-(-OH)-(-OH)-(-COOH)-O-)))---)}}{Molecule C}
    \schemestop
\end{document}
```

[image]